# Bootstrap Nav: Center anchor links in remaining width after nav brand

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a typical bootstrap nav bar. It shows a brand icon and then the navigational anchor links. What I would like to achieve is that my "li" or "a" tags are a width such that they take up all the remaining space in the navbar.

Code is as follows (CSS is traditional out of the box bootstrap 3):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

What I need is for the brand to stay normal width and Home, About, and Contact to take up all the space left in the nav.

I tried playing with the padding. I adjusted the padding left and right to be about 10% which gave me a very close result, but they were not quite centered and over that drops the links to the next line.

I looked around to see if anyone had a similar issue, but didn't find it. Any takers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the width percentage based on the size of the `brand` so your links aren't adjusted to below the navbar when the viewport resizes.

```css
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav > li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Awesome! I just needed to play with the li size to get each on to be a little wider, but this works as requested! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Will you try this:

```
.navbar-header {
    width: 15%;
}
ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 85%;
}
.nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 28.33%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You'll also need to do some different styling for small devices too.